# Convert a python string in a integer list form to a proper list of integers

Tags: python

I have a string as `[u'[15]']`. I need it as a list with an int i.e. `[15]`
I tried `ast.literal_eval()`
But it gives the error

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: That seems like a list, are you sure, you do not have a list?

Comment: <type 'list'> when I print type(value). where value=[u'[15]']

Comment: oh I understood the problem I should do ast.literal_eval(value[0]). Is that correct?

Comment: @user77005, yes, you cannot call literal_eval on a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *list* with a unicode string inside, you need to access the element inside the list and call literal_eval on that:

```
from ast import literal_eval

print literal_eval([u'[15]'][0])
[15]
```

You are getting an error by trying to pass the list to literal_eval not the string inside.

```
In [2]:  literal_eval(literal_eval([u'[15]']))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7468abfb5acf> in <module>()
----> 1 literal_eval(literal_eval([u'[15]']))

/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     78                 return left - right
     79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
---> 80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 
     82 

/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in _convert(node)
     77             else:
     78                 return left - right
---> 79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
     80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81
```

Answer (score 2):

I am getting your error, when I pass in the list , Example -

```
>>> a = [u'[15]']
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

If I pass in a string like - `"[u'[15]']"` , I do not get any error -

```
>>> a = "[u'[15]']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
[u'[15]']
```

Seems like you have a list, instead of a string, if so, you can iterate over the list and then pass in the element to ast.literal_eval , to get your element. Example -

```
>>> a = [u'[15]']
>>> import ast
>>> for i in a:
...     ast.literal_eval(i)
...
[15]
```

You can store each element in a list of its own, or if you are sure there is only one element you can also do -

```
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(a[0])
>>> x
[15]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: For the final code snippet you have, what is type(x)?

Comment: It is list . Added that to answer.